# R: Error converting character type to numeric type when using select_if() and gsub()

Tags: r, dplyr, type-conversion, pipeline

I have a dataset of multiple types. It was created in an Excel spreadsheet so some numbers contain commas (e.g. 1,346 instead of 1346). Hence, making them of type character instead of numeric.

Here's what I attempted to make the conversion:

```
df[-2] %>% 
  select_if(is.character) %>% 
  as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df))
```

I am excluding the second column from the selection as it is a valid character type for my analysis.

The error I am getting is:

```
Error in df[-2] %>% select_if(is.character) %>% as.numeric(gsub(",",  : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to do this to replace the `,` to blank (`""`) on all the `character` columns, use `mutate` with `across` as `gsub/sub` etc works on `vector` as input and not on `data.frame`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ as.numeric(str_remove_all(., ','))))
```

---

If we want to exclude the second column

```
df1 <- df %>%
       mutate(across(c(where(is.character), -2), ~ 
               as.numeric(str_remove_all(., ','))))
```

---

Note that `select_if` or `select(where`, will only select those columns from the original data.  If the intention is to replace the `,` in the original dataset columns, use `mutate` with `across`

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = 1:5, col2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
    col3 = c("1,2", "1,5", "1,3", "1,44", "1,46"), col4 = c("1,2", 
    "1,5", "1,3", "1,44", "1,46")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: This has removed the commas but the columns are still of type character. As I need to select the columns I intended to use a pipe to avoid having to convert each feature individually. How can your code above be transformed to include this?

Comment: @Joehat just wrap with `as.numeric`.  sorry forgot about that.  I updated the post

Comment: Brilliant! One final thing... I need to exclude the second column from the selection as it contains valid character types. By doing df[-2] in your example above it would just exclude it completely. Is there a way the code could be modified again to avoid having to merge that columns into the new df1 dataset?

Comment: @Joehat To prevent bugs, it is better to specify the column name insted of column number i.e. -2 can be -col2